# Iterating through a set

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, set

I have a set of ints set something; of length 52. 
I am using cycles to iterate through the set like this:

```
for(iterator A from 1st to 48th element)
 for(iterator B from A+1 to 49th element)
  for(iterator C from B+1 to 50th element)
   for(iterator D from C+1 to 51th element)
    for(iterator E from D+1 to 52th element)
    {
       //save the values from the actual positions in set in array[5]
    }
```

First I tried to make it with an iterator but then I realised that it's not possible to start an iterator from the `position of another iterator +1`. 
Then I tried to use pointers and jump through the values but I correctly assigned only the first value and then I can't jump on second etc.

My code was:

```
set<int> tableAll;
for(int i=4; i!=52; ++i) 
  tableAll.insert(i);

const int * flop1 = & * tableAll.begin();
cout << * flop1 << endl;
flop1++;
cout << * flop1 << endl;
```

When I `cout` the value of pointer `flop1`, I get 4 and that's ok, but when I increase it and again `cout` on screen, I get 0, then, 49, then 0, then 1, then 0 instead 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9.

So how to iterate through my set correctly? I assume using pointers will be faster then some iterator solution.

Comment: What's your understanding of the `48th` element of a set, since a set doesn't have the concept of order? Perhaps a vector is better suited?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Assuming it's `std::set`, then it certainly does have a concept of order.

Comment: What's difficult about starting an iterator from the position of another iterator + 1? Just initialize the iterator from the other iterator and then increment it. `for (auto newIterator = oldIterator; ++NewIterator != set.end();)`

Comment: @MikeSeymour from an implementation point of view, yes, but logically, not really.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz OK, that looks easy, but then how to stop iterating 3 elements before the set.end()? And isn't some pointer solution much faster?

Comment: @LukasSalich: Using that solution, you don't need to stop iterating 3 elements before the end; the inner loops will simply reach the end immediately and do nothing.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I just want to iterate through all elements, so I think the order doesn't matter. I assume the order isn't changing if I don't change it.

Answer (score 4):

You absolutely can iterate from an offset from another iterator:

```
for (auto a(std::begin(mySet)), a_end(std::prev(std::end(mySet), 4));
        a != a_end; ++a)
    for (auto b(std::next(a)), b_end(std::next(a_end); b != b_end; ++b)
        ...
```

In C++03, you can write `next` and `begin` for compatibility:

```
template<typename Iterator> Iterator next(Iterator it, int n = 1) {
    std::advance(it, n);
    return it;
}

template<typename Iterator> Iterator prev(Iterator it, int n = 1) {
    std::advance(it, -n);
    return it;
}

for (std::set<int>::const_iterator a(mySet.begin()),
        a_end(std::prev(mySet.end(), 4)); a != a_end; ++a)
    for (std::set<int>::const_iterator b(std::next(a)),
            b_end(std::next(a_end)); b != b_end; ++b)
        ...
```

Comment: Although this does about twice as many iterations as necessary. Loop conditions of `a != mySet.end()` will give the same results and will probably be rather more efficient.

Comment: @MikeSeymour ah, didn't see that the size of the set was 52.  That makes it easier.

Comment: I could have sworn `std::next` was in C++03, but docs back you up

Comment: Have u tried it? That advance didn't work for me in set. I tried it before asking. Edit: Maybe I haven't included iterator or something, I try again.

Comment: There is `boost::next()` for older compilers. And `std::advance()` surely works with `set::iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

This code is not optimal as it do unneeded iterator comparisions, but works and is simply:

```
set<int> tableAll;
for(int i=0; i!=52; ++i)
  tableAll.insert(i);

for( set<int>::iterator iA=tableAll.begin(); iA != tableAll.end(); ++iA  )
    for( set<int>::iterator iB=iA; ++iB != tableAll.end();  )
        for( set<int>::iterator iC=iB; ++iC != tableAll.end();  )
            for( set<int>::iterator iD=iC; ++iD != tableAll.end();  )
                for( set<int>::iterator iE=iD; ++iE != tableAll.end();  ) 
{
   cout<<*iA<<' '<<*iB<<' '<<*iC<<' '<<*iD<<' '<<*iE<<endl;
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't work, iA should stop 5 elements before end, iB 4, iC 3, iA 2 and iA 1 element before end.

Comment: It does. You even do not test it right? Last line printed is “47 48 49 50 51”.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to copy the `set` to a temporary `std::vector`.
All operations you do in the loops are natural for a vector and O(1) (except for the loops themselves of course)
That's easier to read, to write, and should run a **lot** faster.

Comment: Really? I thought that forward iterating should be faster or at least same fast in set as in vector.

Comment: The exact timing depends on the implementation. `set` is usually a rb-tree. That means sometimes it has to traverse great parts of tree to get the next element. And that's only *the* next element. To get the nth element it has to repeat this n times. There is no shortcut. For `vector` it's always (a very short) constant time, no matter if you want the next or the nth element.

Comment: Ok, so I tell you what I need in whole code: 
1) some container to store values without using indexes: the insert and erase in set look best for me
2) iterate from these values from begin to end: they don't have to be sorted and the container doesn't have to check if the values are unique because they are

..I think that's everything and on first look I thought that set is best for it

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/get_allocator/ ..the example code looks like solution to my problem, I will iterate the set through pointers, I just didn't know how to do that...

Comment: Allocators are rather special stuff. You shouldn't care about them for everyday work. The example does not really use a `set` it (mis)uses its allocator to create an array.  According your conditions, `std::vector` is actually the best choice. Since you don't care for order, all you need is `push_back()` which appends a new value. Erase an element of an unsorted vector is of course more expensive. If you really need insert **and** erase, then use a `set` for initialization and than copy the contents to a `vector` for processing.